# How to use an Xbox One controller wirelessly with a PC?

Tags: pc, controllers, xbox-one

As I understand it, the Xbox One controller uses a standard USB port, which allows someone to connect it to a PC with a standard USB cable.

A wired solution does not meet my needs and it is very difficult to find the "Xbox 360 Wireless Controller for PC" bundle in stores these days. I would like to know if anyone has been able to use an Xbox One controller with a PC in a wireless fashion by substituting wireless USB for the cable.

I imagine this could be done by finding a receiver compatible with the controller or by attaching a dongle to the controller that replaces the cable? (Similar to how those cheap mice for laptops work.)

Answer (score 6):

The wireless Xbox One controller for PC will be [available this fall](http://www.engadget.com/2015/06/09/xbox-one-wireless-adapter-for-pc/)!

However it does have some [requirements](http://www.polygon.com/2015/6/9/8752747/xbox-one-wireless-controller-adapter-will-only-work-with-windows-10):

> The Xbox Wireless Adapter for Windows, which will allow an Xbox One controller to work on a Windows computer, will only support **Windows 10.** It is compatible with either **USB 2.0 or 3.0** connection.

Comment: If your running 7 or 8, upgrading to 10 is currently free, via system update.

Comment: @Timelord64 nice try Bill, we know it's you.

Answer (score -3):

You can use an wireless xbox controller with a pc if you have an xbox controller wireless adapter.

Here is an example of one:
[http://www.amazon.com/Xbox-Wireless-Gaming-Receiver-Windows/dp/B000HZFCT2](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000HZFCT2)

Comment: This adapter is for the Xbox 360, not the Xbox One.